# Creating an array of objects causes an issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I create the two following objects:

```
bool    Reception::createNProcess()
{
  for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
    {
      Process           *pro = new Process; // forks() at construction
      Thread            *t = new Thread[5];

      this->addProcess(pro); // Adds the new process to a vector
      if (pro->getPid() == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
         {
           pro->addThread(&t[i]); // Adds the new thread to a vector
           t[i].startThread();
         }
      }
}
```

Where I create 3 processes (that I have encapsulated in `Process`) and create 5 threads in each of these processes.

But I'm not sure the following line is correct:

```
Thread            *t = new Thread[5];
```

Because my two functions `addProcess` and `addThread` both take a pointer to `Process` and `Thread` respectively and yet the compiler asks for a reference to `t[i]` for `addThread` and I don't understand why.

```
void    Process::addThread(Thread *t)
{
  this->threads_.push_back(t);
}

void    Reception::addProcess(Process *p)
{
  this->createdPro.push_back(p);
}
```

`createdPro` is defined in the `Reception` class as follows:

```
 std::vector<Process *>        createdPro;
```

and `threads_` in the `Process` class like such:

```
 std::vector<Thread *>         threads_;
```

And the error message (as obvious as it is) is as follows:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Process::addThread(Thread&)’
>        pro->addThread(t[i]);
>
> process.hpp:29:10: note: candidate: void Process::addThread(Thread*)
>      void   addThread(Thread *);
>
> process.hpp:29:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Thread’ to ‘Thread*’

Even though I defined my `Thread` as a pointer.

Comment: Can you please show the definition of `threads_` and `createdPro` ?

Comment: Ok ! Thanks. There is no mismatch of pointer with obects here.  But coul you also show the exact error message, please ?

Comment: `pro->addThread(&t[i]);` looks correct to me based on what you have posted. What do you mean by "compiler asks for a reference to t[i] for addThread" ? You should post the exact error message

Comment: I thought I declared a pointer to Thread, am I wrong in that assumption? I'm not used to manipulating an array of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the member function to take a pointer:

```
void Process::addThread(Thread *t)
{
    ...
}
```

You then invoke this function for `&t[i]`, which is a pointer and should work perfectly:

```
      pro->addThread(&t[i]); // Adds the new thread to a vector
```

You could also invoke it with `t+i` and it would still be ok. However your error message tells us something different:  the compiler doesn't find a match for `pro->addThread(t[i]);`  (i.e. the `&` is missing).

Either you made a typo in your question, or you made a typo in your code.  Or you have another invocation somewhere where you've forgotten the ampersand: `t[i]` would of course designate an object (it's equivalent to `*(t+i)` ) and not a pointer, and cause the error message you have ([demo mcve](http://ideone.com/xlqiim))